# CSS - Styling a header / nav

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a header / nav for a site which is proving a little tricky. I have a PSD image of how it needs to look - 
[image: Header]

I'm okay with the logo but I'm struggling with how to fit all the other elements around each other on the right hand side. Usually I only have the logo and the nav links. Here's the code -

**HTML**

```
<header>
        <h1 id="logo">
            <img src="images/Logo.png">
        </h1>
        <div id="phoneandemail">
          <h3>
                <img src="images/phone.png" alt="phone" >
                <p>0113 220 5265</p>
            </h3>
            <h3>
                <img src="images/email.png">
                <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
            </h3>
        </div>

          <nav>
            <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
            <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
          </nav>

        <h3>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </h3>


    </header>
```

I'm using reset & skeleton css grid alongside my CSS. Here's what I've got so far -

**CSS**

```
header {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    z-index: 10;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

nav a {
    color: #bdc3c7;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#phoneandemail {
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

h3 i {
    float: right;
}
```

Do I need to float them all right or is there a more appropriate way to group them all together like the PSD image? I need to get it as close as that as I can.

Comment: What are you struggling with ?? Those social logos on the right?

Comment: You should see it as a grid. First thing to do: Make two parts. The left side (with the logo) and right side with the navigation. Therefor you need two divs (left-header, right-header). Float them both left so they're on the same row. (don't forget to put them in a container div so they keep the same height). 

The left part (logo) wasn't the problem so I focus on the right part. Again, split it in a grid. First make again, two divs (one for the top part, and one for the bottom part). Keep doing this until you've what you need.

Comment: @RohitJaiswal Yes, I can't get them to group around each other like the image above.

Comment: @JeroenE I need to 'size' everything as well, right?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Let me work this out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get used to this very easily and this is how:
Make a grid and color each div so you know what you're doing. Don't fill in anything yet before you've got the grid you need. So let's take of:

First make two divs that float left so you have the first part of your grid:

```
<header>
    <div class="left-header"></div>
    <div class="right-header"></div>
</header>
```

Now you've got the first part (the left side for the logo, right side for the navigation etc.). Secondly give them colors so you know what you're changing and what you're doing. Beside that give them all options they need like width, floats etc.

```
.left-header { background:red; width:100px; float:left; height:50px; }
.right-header { background:blue; max-width:200px; float:left; height:50px; }
```

**Note:** *I also use "heights" in this example just to make sure something appears. If you don't give heights/widths you won't see anything appear on your screen. But don't forget to remove the heights on the end. The content will generate your height.*

Keep in mind: I gave them a width, but you should check in photoshop what width it should be. I guess it should be responsive, so give the left div a width (as it has a fixed-width image) and the right side an min-width and or max-width so your navigation will stay responsive. Width's are bad when you want to keep it responsive. So only use where really necessary.

Your first part is done: the "left-header" only needs an image yet. But wait for that until you've done your grid. Secondly we've to finish your "right-header" part.

Once again: There are two divs needed. A top div (for phone and mail) and a bottom div for the navigation and social icons.

```
<header>
    <div class="left-header"></div>
    <div class="right-header">
         <div class="right-header-top"></div>
         <div class="right-header-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Once again give them colors. Heights are not necessary. The content will do that. But as we don't have content yet, add some heights to the elements for now.
Now the bottom part is again two divs; left and right (left part for the navigation, right for the social icons).  etc...

Please note: There are plenty of frameworks that have this kind of grids. But to learn how it works you should try this. If you're happy with the grid you made and it's like it should be, then remove the colors and add the content.

Example of this part:

```
<header>
    <div class="left-header"></div>
    <div class="right-header">
        <div class="right-header-top"></div>
        <div class="right-header-bottom">
            <div class="right-header-bottom-left"></div>
            <div class="right-header-bottom-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<style>
    .left-header { background:red; width:100px; float:left; height:50px; }
.right-header { background:blue; max-width:200px; float:left; height:50px; }

.right-header-top { background:green; width:100px; height:25px; }
.right-header-bottom { background:orange; width:100px; height:25px; } <!-- You won't see this as it's behind the blue and gray part. -->

.right-header-bottom-left { float:left; height:25px; width:50%; background:blue;}
.right-header-bottom-right { float:left; height:25px; width:50%; background:gray; }
</style>
```

Comment: This is great but when i remove the content and just leave the divs I just get a blank canvas?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry for that. Put some content in it so you can see what happens or give them some height for now. But don't forget to remove that. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Editted my post. Did this help you?

Comment: I'd use flexbox and `justify-content: space-between` but whatever, old school method still works :) OP you should always test and develop with either real content or lorem ipsum _faux text_, neither empty elements nor "words" made of 40x the same letter if your language doesn't a word that long ^^ (URLs can be that long though)

Comment: @JeroenE As i've already set rules for the (main) header (see above) should I set height to 100%?

Comment: @FelipeAls I do agree that flexbox etc. are much more efficient. How ever, to learn how this works and to build better websites understanding it would be very helpfull. Building it "the old school way" will definitly help you become a better developer. So that's why I explained it this way. Please read my last note of the post.

Comment: @JeroenE I've found this really helpful:)

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead No, putting the height to 100% will mean that your full screen will fill with the header. This example will just learn you how to work with grids and how to build them yourself.

Comment: @JeroenE The right-header-top / right-header-bottom aren't stacking on top of each other, the 'top' seems to be competing with the right-header class

Comment: @JeroenE I've got it after some fiddling - thank you. Are there any extra rules I need to add when I put the images and nav into this now so they all fit? Any sizing or position: fixed etc?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead First give it a try. ;)

Comment: @JeroenE How come max-width changes things? When I apply it to the righ-header class it overules the background color rules for the sub classes.